# Flutter - refresh single element in ListView on ListTile tap

Tags: firebase, listview, flutter

Here is flow I want to achieve:

- get list of items and put it in ListView as ListTile
- on item tap update item status in Firebase (from unread to read)
- refresh single one item in List
- navigate to other
- on click back button get list with updated element - marked as readed

Is there any possibility to refresh single one element in ListView on tap? By now I tried to use  setState() method but It didn't work - item is updated in Firebase but change doesn't appears in list until I refresh page manually.

onTap function

```
onTap: () {
  setState(() {
    _notifications[index].data['viewed'] = true;
  });

  _userService.setNotificationAsClicked(_notifications[index].data['id']);
  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(_notifications[index].data['routing']);
},
```

BackButton:

```
return Container(
  child: BackButton(
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    },
  ),
);
```

EDIT:
It works when in back button I use Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(...) instead of Navigator.pop(), but in this case I need to scroll down and reload again all elements...

***I FOUND SOLUTION!!!***

All I need to do was change storing List with DocumentSnapshot to List with data from DocumentSnapshot.